# w3validator error which I cannot correct

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I've almost competed a project that I have been working on for sometime now, I  used w3validator to check for errors and 
there happens to be a few in the footer which I can't seem to resolve.

I have added my jsfiddle  (https://jsfiddle.net/webi108/zuet60sv/)

1. Error: Start tag a seen but an element of the same type was already open.

From line 307, column 45; to line 307, column 48

stimonials↩

2. Error: Self-closing syntax (/>) used on a non-void HTML element. Ignoring the slash and treating as a start tag.

From line 307, column 45; to line 307, column 48

stimonials↩

```
  <footer class="container footer">
    <div class="row">
      <!--section 1 links-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <div id="cat-1">
          <h6>About</h6>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">About Company<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help <a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Returns<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sizes<a/></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!--section 2 lniks-->
        <h6>Useful Links</h6>
        <div id="cat-2">
          <ul>

            <li><a href="#">Testimonials<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store Location<a/></li>
            <li><a href="#">Site Map<a/></li>

            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <!--section 3 links-->
        <h6>Documentation</h6>
        <div id="cat-3">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><li>RISQS Certificate</li><a/>
            <li><a href="#"><li>Insurance</li><a/>
            <li><a href="#">Library<a/></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!--section 4 links and logs-->
      <div class="col-sm-3">

      </div>


  </footer>
```

Comment: Typo: `<a/>`. The slash in an end tag goes at the **front** (just like most other end tags in your code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't closed all you links. `<a href=""></a>` Should be the correct way to use them.

Further more you have opened some list items within a list item a the third list, without closing them.

And last but not least you didn't close the `<div class="row">`

The below code should work now.

```html
<footer class="container footer">
    <div class="row">
        <!--section 1 links-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>About</h6>
            <div id="cat-1">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Returns</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sizes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--section 2 lniks-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>Useful Links</h6>
            <div id="cat-2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Store Location</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Site Map</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <!--section 3 links-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <h6>Documentation</h6>
            <div id="cat-3">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">RISQS Certificate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Library</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--section 4 links and logs-->
        <div class="col-sm-3">

        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```